# How to identify which geckodriver.exe is being used?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I have multiple copies of **geckodriver.ex**e on my computer, they may be of different version, I run my python scripts from my computer without knowing which one is actually being used. I did not explicitly specify the geckodriver.exe in the script:
...

```
path2ff = os.environ.get('LOCALAPPDATA') + r'\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'

binary = FirefoxBinary(path2ff)
dr = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile=profile)
```

Now I need to compile the scripts into an executable to distribute to other users, and don't know which **geckodriver.exe** I need to send.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Heinz

Answer (score 1):

At a high-level I'd use the WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) library for Python to list all the processes running on your machine, find geckodriver.exe, then get it's location on your system.

To get list of processes try:

```
import wmi

# Initializing the wmi constructor
f = wmi.WMI()
 
# Printing the header for the later columns
print("pid   Process name")
 
# Iterating through all the running processes 
for process in f.Win32_Process():
     
    # Displaying the P_ID and P_Name of the process
    print(f"{process.ProcessId:<10} {process.Name} {process.CommandLine}")
```

In the `process` object of that `for` loop read the `CommandLine` variable, which will give you the path.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process for WMI documentation.

Sample Output:

```
pid     Process name   CommandLine
14404      RuntimeBroker.exe C:\Windows\System32\RuntimeBroker.exe -Embedding
14616      nvsphelper64.exe None
14636      NVIDIA Share.exe "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GeForce Experience\NVIDIA Share.exe"
```

Comment: Koby, the latest wmi support python 3.5 while I am using python 3.7

Comment: @Heinz : I just tried using the WMI module with python 3.9 and it worked successfully.  It should also work for the python 3.7 that you're using.